# Changing the colour of filtered text in binding data source

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, colors, find

Would you help me
I want to change the colour of found text in datagridview binded with bindingsource,
I have searched a lot but couldnt find the answer
Here is my code

```
private void Search()
    {
        var c = new[] {' '};
        var parts = searchTxt.Text.Split(c, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var condition = string.Empty;
        foreach (var t in parts)
        {
            if (condition.Trim().Length > 0) condition += " and ";
            condition += (string.Format(" (Family LIKE '*{0}*' or Email LIKE '*{0}*'" +
                                        " or Phone1 LIKE '*{0}*' or Phone2 LIKE '*{0}*'      or Phone3 LIKE '*{0}*' or Fax LIKE '*{0}*'" +
                                        " or CellPhone LIKE '*{0}*' or TypeofWork LIKE '*{0}*' or Address LIKE '*{0}*' or Brands LIKE '*{0}*') ",
                                        t));
        }
        ((BindingSource) dataGridView1.DataSource).Filter = condition;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        if (row.Cells[6].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
            row.Cells[6].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
    catch (Exception){}
}
```

Comment: If it change it will change all row's colour , I want just to change the searched text in the cell.
the searched text is the text in the search textbox which is trimmed to be found.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
But there is two questions:

1  when I search book and bookmark contains it I want to change the the colour of Just book not all the bookmark.

2  Should I repeat the code for all the column??

Comment: @Morteza I have a suggestion, add an image of your datagridview with data loaded so that I can understand it better, it will be great if you add the fields of your table too.

Comment: Do you mean that if a bookmark is "C# in depth" and you search the word "C#" it only changes the color of "C#" and the color of " in depth" not changes?

Comment: @Morteza AFAIK that's unsupported in datagridview, if you insist on such behaviour you need to get your hands dirty and write your own gridview. Currently the littlest part you can paint is cell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21370/discussion-between-morteza-and-mahdi-tahsildari)

Answer (score 0):

To implement this you need to have the RowDataBound event for Grid and inside just call the code referred by mahdi tahsildari

Answer (score 0):

Here SW is (searched string)

```
       private void DgNewItem_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)

       {

      int strt = 0;

      int cnt = -1;

      int idx = -1;

        if ((((e.RowIndex >= 0) && (e.ColumnIndex >= 0))))

       {

         e.Handled = true;

    e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);


             **//string sw = GetSearchWord(e.ColumnIndex);**

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sw))
            {
                string val = e.FormattedValue.ToString();

                int sindx = val.ToLower().IndexOf(sw.ToLower());
                if ((sindx >= 0))
                {
                    while (strt != -1)
                    {
                        strt = val.ToLower().IndexOf(sw.ToLower(), idx + 1);
                        cnt += 1;
                        idx = strt;

                        //int numberOfTrues = Regex.Matches(val, sw).Count;
                        // the highlite rectangle
                        if (strt != -1)
                        {
                            Rectangle hl_rect = new Rectangle();
                            hl_rect.Y = (e.CellBounds.Y + 2);
                            hl_rect.Height = (e.CellBounds.Height - 5);
                            // find the size of the text before the search word
                            // and the size of the search word
                            string sBefore = val.Substring(0, idx);
                            string sWord = val.Substring(idx, sw.Length);
                            Size s1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, sBefore, e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds.Size);
                            Size s2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, sWord, e.CellStyle.Font, e.CellBounds.Size);
                            // adjust the widths to make the highlite more accurate
                            if ((s1.Width > 5))
                            {
                                hl_rect.X = (e.CellBounds.X
                                + (s1.Width - 5));
                                hl_rect.Width = (s2.Width - 6);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hl_rect.X = (e.CellBounds.X + 2);
                                hl_rect.Width = (s2.Width - 6);
                            }
                            // use darker highlight when the row is selected
                            SolidBrush hl_brush;
                            if (((e.State & DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
                            != DataGridViewElementStates.None))
                            {
                                hl_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGoldenrod);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                hl_brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Violet);
                            }
                            // paint the background behind the search word
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(hl_brush, hl_rect);
                            hl_brush.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // paint the content as usual
            e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
        }
    }
```